# Lie theory and particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, group-theory, lie-algebra

I have recently been reading *Intro to Lie algebras and representation theory* by Humphreys, and when I am finished I am interested in reading about Lie groups and Lie algebras and their applications to particle physics.

> Is there a book that assumes basic knowledge of Lie algebras, and no knowledge of lie groups and particle physics/quantum mechanics?

I have seen Howard Georgi's book, but it assumes good knowledge of particle physics.

In addition, I do not know differential geometry.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think this question can be taken as not the question about Lie groups/algebras books, but as the question about particle physics books. Then it is not duplicate (or a duplicate of some other question).

Comment: I would like to mention (1) Halzen, Martin _Quarks and Leptons_, which shows use of Lie groups and representations in particle physics (no background needed), and (2) Rubakov _Classical Theory of Gauge Fields_, which shows use of Lie groups/algebras and reps in the quantum theory of fields (mostly on simplest classical level). Here familiarity with SR, electrodynamics and Lagrangian formalism is assumed.

Comment: Yeah, I was basically looking for particle physics books that apply these concepts, but just don't assume knowledge of Lie groups, but assume knowledge of Lie algebras.

Comment: Seems to me that groups are of more use than algebras without groups. But the notion of group is very simple - it is the exponentiation of an algebra. I don't think you will have problems readind these books.